# Actionlib notifications not received

Tags: ros, actionlib, simpleactionclient

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to notify to both action server and action client when any of them dies. I would like the client to be notified by the server whenever this server dies. Similarly, I would like the server to be notified if the current client dies for some reason.

I am using a simple action server with the execute callback option, and a client with the done, active and feedback callbacks.

In the destructor of the node containing the action server, I have added the following code:

```
if ( as_.isActive() )
{
  as_.setAborted();
}
as_.shutdown();
```

Unfortunately, the client never gets any kind of notification. I was expecting the done callback to receive an aborted status, or something similar.

For the client notification, I have tried to use the isServerConnected() and getState() functions from the node's destructor, but I always get the same result whether the server is running or not: *isServerConnected()*=0 and *getState()*=Aborted. I have also called *cancelGoal()* and *stopTrackingGoal()* to let the server cancel the current goal, but they seem to have no effect.

Maybe I am missing some important key points. Any Suggestion?

Joan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10707/actionlib-notifications-not-received/) by [joan](https://answers.ros.org/users/881/joan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2011-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I've run into this before when trying to do something similar. In my case, ROS had already shutdown when my destructor was called which meant that no actionlib related messages were going over the wire.

There's actually a tool called [bond](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bond) that would be perfect for your use case. Not only will it let you know when nodes go down cleanly, it'll also let you know if they go down from a crash. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2